# How to use u64 as seed

Tags: pda, seed

I am creating pda accounts with a variable seed. To do this I created an account with a counter u64. For every pda account created, the counter will increment in 1, so the seeds of the account created will be "seed"+counter (1, 2, 3...)

I can succesfully initiate the pda like this:
Rust:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitiatePda<'info> {
...
    #[account(init, seeds = [b"seed1".as_ref(), counter_pda.counter.to_be_bytes().as_ref()], bump, payer=payer, space = 50)]
    account_pda: Account<'info, SomeStruct>,
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"counter_account".as_ref()], bump)]
    counter_pda: Account<'info, CounterInfo>,
...
}

#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct CounterInfo {
    pub counter: u64,
}
```

In Js, to find the PDA, I want to pass a number a get the account pubkey

```
async function getPda(id) {
    return await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [Buffer.from("seed1"), new BN(id).toArrayLike(Buffer, "be", 8)],
        PROGRAM_ID
    );
}
```

Up to here it works fine, the Pda is created succesfully.

The problem is when I want to use the account_pda in another instruction. I cant make the getPda function on Js find the same account as the one in Rust.

My code:
Rust:

```
    pub fn set_account_config(
        ctx: Context<AccountConfig>,
        id: u64,
    ) -> Result<()> {
...
...
        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(id: u64)]
pub struct AccountConfig<'info> {
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"seed1".as_ref(), id.to_be_bytes().as_ref()], bump = account_pda.bump)]
    account_pda: Account<'info, SomeStruct>,
    /// CHECK: Just testing
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
}
```

Js:

```
const id = 5 //testing if can set the fifth account config
const [account_pda] = await getPda(id)

    instructions.push(
        program.instruction.setAccountConfig(
            new BN(id),
            {
                accounts: {
                    payer: wallet.publicKey,
                    accountPda: account_pda,
                },
            }
        )
    );
```

Im getting this error, its like the pda found on js is different than the one on Rust. I think maybe I have to use another thing instead of id.to_be_bytes().

```
> Program logged: "Instruction: SetAccountConfig"
> Program logged: "AnchorError caused by account: account_pda. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated."
> Program logged: "Left:"
> Program logged: "5Dq6kPGZKfGbWo1TgPjCFNXAryikhLoaRkM2LiSCqzbc"
> Program logged: "Right:"
> Program logged: "3FDBrtJKDyZSU2iFLvWnnyHw2Gusfv8ADTDg3hpkVVRx"
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The seeds should be:

```
#[account(init, seeds = [b"seed1".as_ref(), &id.to_le_bytes()], bump, payer=payer, space = 50)]
```

```
async function getPda(id) {
  return await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [
      Buffer.from("seed1"),
      new BN(id).toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 8),
    ],
    PROGRAM_ID
  );
}
```

Comment: When using 'le', I get an error when initializing the account_pda: > 9LyEyfeTyP9C4XzF4pkZXWs3oZRTsGwYxQnoSSv5UeQk's signer privilege escalated. Its like the pda account passed doesnt match the one on Rust

Comment: I missed something on rust side, editing the answer now.

Comment: Please try to change it as &counter_pda.counter.to_le_bytes()

Comment: Nice, the pda initializes but still getting an error when trying to use that pda in another instruction (Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.). I changed to 'le' in AccountInfo too. Maybe something here: id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()..

Comment: Yeah, the main point is that the u64 should be converted to_le_bytes() in account seeds.

Comment: It finally worked, I was missing to pass the instruction data as the first argument

Comment: Awesome!!! I'm glad it was helpful.